# Small change to code gives AttributeError (Python, Networkx)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, simulation, networkx

I'm currently doing a project which involves using networkx to make an undirected graph with node positions based on a csv file and the class patches having various properties to indicate their positions, status and the indices of each nearest neighbour of each node. An emigration algorithm is then performed on this set of nodes.

I am currently wanting to scale up my code so I can have many more nodes, as this project is astronomical in nature. I was using regular Euclidean distances which is very slow for large populations due to quadratic scaling. I therefore employed a nearest neighbour algorithm to look just at nodes within some distance. I then made a csv of these, i.e. a csv of the indices of each nearest neighbour node. I am then trying to draw edges between these nodes in order for my algorithm to be performed upon the resulting graph.

However once I have made this change the next little block of code gets an AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'pos'.

My code is below and the Euclidean distance calculation is commented out for comparison. The block of code which is breaking is the one immediately after the edge drawing block, it is a sort of set-up for the algorithm which follows. I apologise for the stupid variable names - boba is the nearest neighbour node indices and bubu is the index of the node having edges drawn to it.

I'm stumped here because I don't know how the change is eve connected or why it would throw up this error.

```
nearand = np.genfromtxt('/Users/Skippy/nearand.csv', delimiter = ',',usecols=np.arange(0, 3)) # 3D cartesian co-ordinates of stars


density = 0.14 #Stellar density per cubic parsec
L = 100 # Size of box

Patches = int(0.056*density*L**3+15)


P_init = 0.0001   # Probability that a patch will be occupied at the beginning
Distance = 10 # An arbitrary parameter to determine which patches are     connected

xcoord = nearand[:,0]
ycoord = nearand[:,1]
zcoord = nearand[:,2]

bub = np.asarray(np.linspace(0, Patches, Patches, dtype = 'int'))
print bub
bobbington = np.asarray(np.genfromtxt('bobbington2.csv', delimiter = ',')) # csv of nearest neighbour node indices
bobbington0 = bobbington[:,0]
bobbington1 = bobbington[:,1]
bobbington2 = bobbington[:,2]
bobbington3 = bobbington[:,3]
bobbington4 = bobbington[:,4]
bobbington5 = bobbington[:,5]
bobbington6 = bobbington[:,6]
bobbington7 = bobbington[:,7]
bobbington8 = bobbington[:,8]
bobbington9 = bobbington[:,9]
bobbington10 = bobbington[:,10]
bobbington11 = bobbington[:,11]
bobbington12 = bobbington[:,12]


class patch:
    def __init__(self,status=0,pos=(0,0,0),boba = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,),bubu = 0):
    self.status = status
    self.pos = pos
    self.boba = boba
    self.bubu = bubu
def __str__(self):
    return(str(self.status))

G = nx.Graph()

for i in xrange(Patches):

    Stat = 1 if np.random.uniform() < P_init else 0
    Pos  = (xcoord[i], ycoord[i], zcoord[i])
    Bob = (bobbington0[i],bobbington1[i],bobbington2[i],bobbington3[i],bobbington4[i],bobbington5[i],bobbington6[i],bobbington7[i],bobbington8[i],
bobbington9[i],bobbington10[i],bobbington11[i],bobbington12[i])
    Bubu = bub[i]
    G.add_node(patch(Stat,Pos,Bob,Bubu))

#for p1 in G.nodes():
    #for p2 in G.nodes():
        #Dist = np.sqrt((p1.pos[2] - p2.pos[2])**2 + (p1.pos[1]-p2.pos[1])**2+(p1.pos[0]-p2.pos[0])**2)
        #if Dist <= p1.dist:
        #if Dist <= Distance:
            #G.add_edge(p1,p2)

for i in G.nodes():
    edge1= (i.bubu,i.boba[0])
    edge2= (i.bubu,i.boba[1])
    edge3= (i.bubu,i.boba[2])
    edge4= (i.bubu,i.boba[3])
    edge5= (i.bubu,i.boba[4])
    edge6= (i.bubu,i.boba[5])
    edge7= (i.bubu,i.boba[6])
    edge8= (i.bubu,i.boba[7])
    edge9= (i.bubu,i.boba[8])
    edge10= (i.bubu,i.boba[9])
    edge11= (i.bubu,i.boba[10])
    edge12= (i.bubu,i.boba[11])
    edge13= (i.bubu,i.boba[12])

    G.add_edge(*edge1)
    G.add_edge(*edge2)
    G.add_edge(*edge3)
    G.add_edge(*edge4)
    G.add_edge(*edge5)
    G.add_edge(*edge6)
    G.add_edge(*edge7)
    G.add_edge(*edge8)
    G.add_edge(*edge9)
    G.add_edge(*edge10)
    G.add_edge(*edge11)
    G.add_edge(*edge12)
    G.add_edge(*edge13)

pos = {} # THE BIT CAUSING ISSUES
for i in G.nodes():
    pos[i] = i.pos


occup = [n.status for n in G]   # THIS ALSO HAS NO 'status' ATTRIBUTE ERROR

Time = [0]
Occupancy = [np.sum([n.status for n in G])/float(Patches)]

##Then algorithm goes here##
```

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Comment: There's far too much code here. Please cut it down to the minimum necessary to show the problem. And at least remove the commented-out parts.

Comment: Cut it down, my thinking was context to the wider script might be helpful.

Comment: Can you give the full error message (and tell us which lines it refers to)?

Comment: Absolutely
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/Skippy/Dropbox/indextrialmk2.py in <module>()
    106 for i in G.nodes():
    107     print pos
--> 108     pos[i] = i.pos
    109 
    110 

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'pos'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the variable `bub` appears to me to be a numpy array.

In each patch you create when doing `G.add_node(patch(...))`, the argument `Bubu` is set to be an entry from `bub`.  So it's a number.  Then for that patch, `self.bubu` is a number.

When you add edges, you're adding edges from `i.bubu` to `i.boba[some index]`.  So since `i.bubu` is a number you're creating edges from those numbers to something else.  This will cause networkx to add nodes which are those numbers.

So prior to entering the loop `for i in G.nodes():  pos[i] = i.pos` many of the nodes in `G` are numbers rather than patches.

For these numbers, it does not make sense to refer to `number.pos`.  That's something you've defined for your patch class.

Comment: I see, so if I'm correct, my issue here is because I'm trying to use the indices of the each node in relation to the csv of the co-ordinates to make edges. So `bub` is a list of indices labels and what I was trying to do was draw edges from the indices of one point to one of the nearest neighbours.Say ay row 0 in the csv of coords had nearest neighbours on row 7 and 112, I was trying to draw nodes from star (0,7) and  star(0,112). However I was literally drawing edges between some numbers? The number.pos etc is needed for the rest of the code so would convert_node_labels_to_integers() help me?

Comment: I think I understand this now, thank you. I just need to find a way to make the `bobbington` csv file be the row indices of the position csvs of the nearest neighbours in order to draw the edges between the nodes and their nearest neighbours (I think...)